# Smartfile API key and API password

Tags: python-2.7, web, storage

I've registered for the free developer account at smartfile [www.smartfile.com/‎]. It says I have an existing API key and API password, but nothing is not shown on screen. 

It also prevents me from creating a new key and password pair. Is this a limitation of the "free account" ?

How do I view my applications/accounts default API key and password?

It's not visible anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been fixed now with a new update/fix.

Works fine with no issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bring this to SmartFile's attention! Hopefully this will be helpful:

There was a two part fix to this issue. First, the database problem was fixed as soon as we found out about it. Second, we improved the dialog to show loading indicators and error messages if applicable. You can read more in our help forum thread here: http://smartfile.forumbee.com/t/q427a

Please let me know if you have any other issues!